# JDBC Postgres in Spring Application

Tags: spring, postgresql, jdbc, spring-jdbc

New to spring. Trying to establish postgres connection in spring framework using Java. Eclipse is the editor tool.

**Property 'driverClassName' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not load JDBC driver class [org.postgresql.Driver]**

I have given the connector in build paths etc. Please help.
Not able to figure out what is the issue!

Comment: can you edit and add your pom.xml or your gradle build file, or whatever you are using as built tool .

Comment: The PostgreSQL driver is not on your classpath. Please show your pom or gradle config.

Comment: Check stackoverflow .. this problem probably has a solution from the 1980's.

Comment: You were right. I have to place in WebInf libs as well. I was putting it in only build paths of the overall project. 
Akli, Mark, Karl : Thanks!!